# Set custom ID in collection - AngularFire 7 and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

How can i set a custom ID to a doc in the new Angularfire 7?

i DONT want the auto genereted one..

my code: (this creates a automatic ID, a want to put my own ID)

```js
  addInfos(infos: any) {
    const notesRef = collection(this.firestore, "infos");
    return addDoc(notesRef, infos)
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify your own document ID and then call `setDoc` instead of `addDoc`.

```
addInfos(infos: any) {
  const notesRef = collection(this.firestore, "infos");
  return setDoc(doc(notesRef, "your-id"), infos)
}
```

This is pretty much a direct copy from the Firebase documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), so I recommend spending some time in there to get up to speed.

Comment: Thank you friend.. sorry if it was a silly question.. i was only looking in the angularfire docs.. but they seem to be in the old version.. anyway thanks again!!